# Using non-deterministic list monad to find long Collatz sequences

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I wrote the following code to solve Project Euler's [No. 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14):

The following iterative (Collatz) sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

```
n → n/2 (n is even)
n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
```

Q: Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

And my code:

```
collatz :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatz 1 = [1] 
collatz n = 
    filter (< 1000000) prev >>= poss
    where prev = collatz (n - 1)

poss :: Integer -> [Integer]
poss prev
    | even prev && prev `mod` 3 == 1 && (prev - 1) `div` 3 > 1 = [2 * prev, (prev - 1) `div` 3]
    | otherwise = [2 * prev]
```

Where `collatz n` returns a list of numbers that will generate a Collatz chain of length n. The problem is, I can only either not restrict the result or restrict the whole chain, instead of only the seed number, to be under 1000,000. Is it possible to use this model to solve the problem at all?

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to use a monad? Or are you open to other solutions to the problem?

Comment: I did solve the problem not using monad, but I think this is a good place to see how the list monad works

Comment: You're trying to solve the problem by running the Collatz sequence backwards stating with 1. Let's say you do a breadth-wise expansion. Then your termination condition is "have I seen all of the numbers [1..10^6]  somewhere in my search?" Also, the first time you see a number you want to record the length of the chain to that number. You can stop running the Collatz sequence backwards when you get back to 1, but a sequence could go arbitrarily high before coming back to 1. Maybe use a priority queue to select which numbers to expand next?

Comment: I see the problem now -- since I don't have a way to predict which number will produce the longest chain while end at a point below 1m, there is no way to prioritize the list. Otherwise I could have known the answer in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this approach - while interesting - is fundamentally doomed. Suppose I discover that all the seeds which result in a chain of length 500 are above 2,000,000. How can I know that I won't find that in three more steps there's a seed under 1,000,000 that gets me there? I see no way to know when you're done.

The only viable approach I see to this problem is to compute the collatz length for every number from 1 to 999,999 and then do something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let collatzMax = maximumBy (compare `on` collatzLength) [1..999999]
  print collatzMax
```

On the other hand, this provides a great opportunity to learn about [CAFs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form) since the function `collatzLength` could be naively defined as:

```
collatzLength 1 = 1
collatzLength n | n `mod` 2 == 0 = 1 + collatzLength (n `div` 2)
collatzLength n = 1 + collatzLength (3 * n + 1)
```

And that kind of recursion screams out for a CAF.

Sure, there are memoization modules that will go and build the CAF for you, but building one yourself is a useful exercise. It's a whole little mini-course in lazy infinitely-recursive data structures.

If that defeats you, you can glance at [this spoiler](https://gist.github.com/fizbin/6f498ea97038b29e7abf) of how to use a CAF and then rewrite it using a different data structure. (what about a 10-way tree instead of a binary tree? What about traversing the tree in a different order? Can you remove the call to `showIntAtBase`?)

Comment: Thanks about the extra info, will definitely look into it!

Comment: Note that just by changing the data structure used for the CAF around slightly, I was able to take the total time from ~ 55 seconds to ~ 35 seconds on my laptop. Structure matters, and you should experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is interesting, although not the most efficient one. It could be worth trying, although it'll be probably memory intensive. Some thoughts:

- As some chains can go over 1000000, so you can't just filter out everything less in `collatz`. You need to keep all the numbers in each pass.
- Calling `collatz` this way is inefficient, as it computes the sets all over again. Making it an infinite list that shares values would be more efficient:

  ```
  collatz :: [[Integer]]
  collatz = [1] : map (>>= poss) collatz
  ```
- You need to figure out when you're done. For this you'd need to go through the number lists generated by `collatz` and count how many of them are below 1000000. When you have seen all the numbers below the limit, the last list will contain the numbers with the longest chain.

That said, I'm afraid this approach isn't computationally feasible. In particular, you'll generate exponentially many numbers and exponentially large ones. For example, if the longest chain would be 500, the result of `collatz` in that step would contain numbers up to 2^500. And as mentioned, there is no way to tell which of these huge numbers might be the one leading to the solution, so you can't just discard them.